# Using Keras with Tensorflow as backend to train cifar10 using vgg16.py from keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I used a `pre-trained model of vgg16` provided by keras. [vgg16.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py) 
In vgg16.py, I changed the min input size from 48 to 32 and default from 225 to 32. The dimensions of cifar10 is (nb_samples, 3, 32, 32).

The following is the code :

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.utils import *
from keras.optimizers import SGD
nb_classes = 10
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
print ("Train shape", X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)
print ("Train samples", X_train.shape[0])
print ("Test samples", X_test.shape[0])
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test, nb_classes)
print ("Train shape", X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

base_model = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=True, input_shape=X_train.shape[1:], classes=10)
base_model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.005, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])   
base_model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=256, verbose=1)
base_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=256, verbose=1)
#The commented code gives validation accuracy but above code does not.
#base_model.fit(X_train, Y_train,batch_size=256,nb_epoch=10,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),shuffle=True)
```

The above code works but the weights are initialized randomly.The following is the result :

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
('http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz', 'cifar-10-batches-py')
('Train shape', (50000, 32, 32, 3), (50000, 1))
('Train samples', 50000)
('Test samples', 10000)
('Train shape', (50000, 32, 32, 3), (50000, 10))
Train on 10000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2641s - loss: 2.3138 - acc: 0.111
Epoch 2/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2643s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0974
Epoch 3/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2642 - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0987
Epoch 4/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2643s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0986
Epoch 5/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2728s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0966 
Epoch 6/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2736s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0983
Epoch 7/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2681s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0971
Epoch 8/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2707s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0970
Epoch 9/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2609s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0955
Epoch 10/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2649s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0997
```

This training seems to `saturated with loss=2.3027`.
The code for [cifar10_cnn.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py) by keras uses real-time data augmentation and speed `reduces the speed of above 2000s to 351s of the code.` Any reasons and also accuracy rises to 80% on training set for later but in above case, it is constant at 9%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found after trying different configurations is that `VGG16 architecture is too big` for an image of size 32x32.I tried to use VGG16 until `block3_pool` and then added a `dense 512` fully_connected followed by `softmax classifier` for`10 classes`. Below is modified code:

```
base_model = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False, 
             input_shape=X_train.shape[1:], classes=10)
x = base_model.get_layer('block3_pool').output
x = Flatten(name='Flatten')(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
```

The drawbacks I found in the question model were: 
(i) Reduce the batch size from 256 to 32.
(ii) Normalization of data using mean.
(iii) Data Augmentation should be used using `data_gen` keras function.
(iv) Smaller architecture VGG16 (16 layer) to  `block3_pool` (3 layer).
(v) Reduction in time from 2000s to 900s using above architecture.

The `accuracy` achieved was around `75%`. Is it possible to `further reduce time on CPU` ?
After evaluating the model on test examples of size 10000, I get the following result: 
`['loss', 'acc'] : [2.3033507381439211, 0.10000000000000001]`. 
This is `overfitting`.

Comment: Min size is 48 not 32. Look at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py

Answer (score 1):

I found [this github project](https://github.com/mjiansun/cifar10-vgg16). Here they are using vgg16 on cifar10 with keras. They reach a validation accuracy of over 0.97.

**More precisely:**

- they use the vgg16 up to the layer `'block3_pool'`
- than they adds some fully connected layers

code for the fully connected layers:

```
x = Flatten()(last)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
pred = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

Comment: This link is not available now. I tried to build a model up to the layer 'block3_pool' but I got a 10% accuracy on the validation set. Can you please help me how to fix it? I used padding ='SAME' for all layers.

Comment: The link has changed: https://github.com/mjiansun/cifar10-vgg16. I adjusted it in my post

Comment: Thank you Oliver, I see that some dropout layers were also in the model. Do you know if it is possible to gain over 80% accuracy on cifar10 with "ONLY" convolutional and fully connected layers? and without enlarging the input size?

Comment: Do you know any paper for this implementation?